# About approximation property of supremum

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be a nonempty upper bounded set. So I know that for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\sup A<a+\varepsilon$, where $a$ is an arbitrary element of $A$. But since $x<y+\varepsilon$ (for all $\varepsilon>0$) implies $x\leq y$, $\sup A\leq a$ which is a contradiction. What's wrong?

Comment: $a$ is not an arbitrary element of $A$.  For any particular $\varepsilon > 0$, **there exists** some $a \in A$ with $\sup A < a + \varepsilon$.  The big idea is that you can find elements of $A$ which are arbitrarily close to the supremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $a$ you mention depends on the $\varepsilon$. The property is : for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $a(\varepsilon)\in A$ such that $\sup A<\varepsilon +a(\varepsilon)$.